# C++ Error (C2280) tring to access a deleted function

Tags: c++, sfml, deleted-functions

So, i was trying to make a 2d game with opengl and sfml,
so i created a button class in an input namespace,
i made a render() function in it, but when i call it (no matter wheter i use a pointer or i don't) even if I pass all the required arguments it's still giving
me an error, saying that I'm trying to access a deleted function
here's the Button header:

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "InputManager.h"

namespace input {

class Button {
private:
    bool m_Selected, m_Clicked;
    sf::Vector2f m_Position;
    sf::Sprite m_Sprite;
    sf::Texture m_Texture;
public:
    Button(sf::Vector2f position, sf::Sprite sprite);
    Button(sf::Vector2f position, sf::Texture texture);
    Button(sf::Vector2f position);
    Button();
    ~Button();
    void update(engine::InputManager inputManager);
    void render(sf::RenderWindow window);
    inline bool isClicked() { return m_Clicked; }
    inline bool isSelected() { return m_Selected; }
    inline sf::Vector2f getPosition() { return m_Position; }
    void setPosition(sf::Vector2f position) { m_Position = position; }
};

}
```

here is Button.cpp:

```
#include "Button.h"

namespace input {

Button::Button(sf::Vector2f position, sf::Sprite texture) : m_Position(position), m_Sprite(texture) {
    m_Sprite.setPosition(m_Position);
}

Button::Button(sf::Vector2f position, sf::Texture texture) : m_Position(position), m_Texture(texture) {

    m_Sprite.setTexture(m_Texture);
    m_Sprite.setPosition(m_Position);
}

Button::Button(sf::Vector2f position) : m_Position(position) {
    m_Sprite.setPosition(m_Position);
}

void Button::update(engine::InputManager inputManager) {}

void Button::render(sf::RenderWindow window) {
    window.draw(m_Sprite);
}

Button::~Button() {
    delete &m_Position;
    delete &m_Texture;
    delete &m_Clicked;
    delete &m_Selected;
}
}
```

Here is the main.cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "InputManager.h"
#include "Button.h"

#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 600
#define TITLE "C++ Platformer"

int main() {

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), TITLE, sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar);

sf::Texture ButtonTexture;
ButtonTexture.loadFromFile("Texture.png");
sf::Sprite sprite;
sprite.setTexture(ButtonTexture);

input::Button* button = new input::Button(sf::Vector2f(100.f, 100.f), sprite);

int fps = 0;

int ticks = 0;

sf::Clock clock;
sf::Clock FpsClock;
sf::Time time;
sf::Time Fpstime;

long delta = 0;
long target = 1000000 / 60;

engine::InputManager IManager;

sf::Event ev;
while (window.isOpen()) {
    while (window.pollEvent(ev)) {
        if (ev.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        if (ev.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) window.close();
        if (ev.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) IManager.onKeyDown(ev.key.code);
    }
    time = clock.getElapsedTime();
    if (target > time.asMicroseconds()) {
        clock.restart();
        // UPDATE
        button->update(IManager);

        delta = time.asMicroseconds() % 60;
        target = 1000000 / 60 + delta;
        ticks++;
    } Fpstime = FpsClock.getElapsedTime();
    if (Fpstime.asSeconds() >= 1) { 
        std::cout << "FPS: " << fps << " Ticks: " << ticks << std::endl; 
        FpsClock.restart();
        fps = 0;
    }
    fps++;
    // RENDER
    button->render(window);
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I've searched on microsoft docs and on other stackoverflow questions, but i couldn't find any case like mine, hope someone can help, thanks

Comment: Please include the full error message

Comment: Please add the complete error message of the compiler to your post.

Comment: Base class of `sf::RenderWindow` is `sf::Window` which is derived from `NonCopyable`. You cannot pass `RenderWindow` by value into `Button::render`. Look at [diagram](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1NonCopyable.php). Use references.

Comment: Not the problem but your destructor is going to crash your program.  You only call `delete` on things you call `new` on.  You don't call `new` on the class members so you should not be calling `delete` on them.

Comment: I really can't emphasize it enough. Do not make your first program a game using sfml! It is just too much to digest! Learn to program in C++ using easier topics, like may be text processing or small data manager or something like that. Try implementing a scientific calculator or something else which would not expose to you to complexities of a huge and involved library. Basically, you need to learn how to swim before practicing diving - even though diving might be way more fun.

Comment: Please stop with the manual memory management nonsense. Especially doing it very wrong as you currently do. That destructor of yours is just .. I'll just say, bad ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `sf::RenderWindow` is non-copyable. This is a good thing, because it means that you can't accidentally get confused about having multiple windows, and it's clear when you create a new window and where it is owned. However, in a function signature like

```
void Button::render(sf::RenderWindow window);
```

you are accepting an `sf::RenderWindow` *by value*. This means that whenever you call `Button::render` and pass a window, that window is *copied* before it is received by the function. See the problem?

You need to accept the render window by reference, to make sure you don't try to create a copy:

```
void Button::render(sf::RenderWindow& window);
```

---

Aside: as pointed out by NathanOliver, you try to `delete` all of your instance members in your `Button` destructor, even though they are not pointers, and you didn't specifically allocate them with `new`. Only `delete` what you `new`, and avoid `new`/`delete` altogether if you can.

If you're unsure about what it means to pass by reference, or what `new` and `delete` are for, I would suggest you pick up a copy of a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Oh, thanks, just wanted to let you know that I'm new to C++ so i know i make some silly code

Answer (score 3):

First of all. what the...

```
Button::~Button() {
    delete &m_Position;
    delete &m_Texture;
    delete &m_Clicked;
    delete &m_Selected;
}
```

You shouldn't do that.

But back to your error. It is quite descriptive. You are trying to use a function that was most likely deleted explicitly. Like so:

```
struct Test {
    Test(const Test & other) = delete; 
};
```

Obviously I cannot copy `Test` now because I deleted the copy constructor.

Which is what [sf::RenderWindow](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php) does by inheriting from [sf::NonCopyable](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1NonCopyable.php) class.

And since your `render()` method takes it by copy and not reference. It obviously tries to do something it was forbidden.

You should change from this:

```
void Button::render(sf::RenderWindow window)
```

To this:

```
void Button::render(sf::RenderWindow & window)
```